# Do I need to use firebase for Android Push Notifications?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-push-notification

I am developing an application in React Native.  I have created push notification keys in OIS.  Easy!  But for android, I am not using firebase at all, and the google play console is very confusing. I can not find where to create or download the keys for push notifications.

I tried API Access in the google....

I was eventually sent to the google cloud platform and attempted something with a service account.

ANDDDD.... I am lost..

All I want is the android keys for push notifications....

Comment: If you are not using a push notification service why do you need the keys?

Comment: I want to create push notifications for the google play app. However, I am not using the firebase database.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Service Accounts tab and in Firebase admin SDK page, just click Generate new private key button. You'll get a json file downloaded that contains your keys.

In case you need to select a admin sdk configuration snippet, you can select nodejs.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I understand you correctly, I can use the Service Accounts tab to generate a private key for push notifications?   I am not using firebase as a database.  So we when you say "Service Accounts tab and in Firebase" You mean "Service accounts tab OR in firebase"?

Comment: Service Accounts tab. But first you need to create an app in Firebase. I hope you've created one.  Thats why I put less details. You need to create an app by submitting required details there. then go to app settings. on that page, you will find Service accounts tab like this one https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6pj7iwuecfkv56/Screenshot%20from%202020-08-12%2016-51-55.png?dl=0

Comment: Oops, no I haven't created an app in Firebase, because I didn't think I needed it.  I think this is where I am confused because I have always viewed Firebase as a Database and less of a Management system.  So I need to create a Firebase system for my App and then get the Push notification keys from there?  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. once you start plying with firebase console, you'll get to understand it easily and much helpful.